# How can I use Atom as the default editor for "open"?

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to set [Atom](https://atom.io/) as my default editor for `open`.

In order to do this, I set in my `.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR="atom -nw"
```

and reload the file with `source .bashrc`. Anyway, when I try to open a text file through `open filename`, it always opens it with TextEdit.

I also tried variations of the above, such as `export EDITOR=atom`, or exporting `VISUAL`.

I am sure that `.bashrc` gets loaded on login.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: A useful and related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390709/how-to-open-atom-editor-from-command-line-in-os-x

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `open` command is part of OS X and uses Finder's default “Open With…” application to open the file, just like double-clicking it in Finder. `$EDITOR` is used for things like `fc` where it is used as the default command-line editor (a replacement for `vim` or `emacs`).

To use Atom with the `open` command, you can select a file of the type you want in Finder, press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>+<kbd>`I`</kbd> for “Get Info”, and then change “Open With:” to Atom, and click “Change All…”.

Alternatively you can define an alias like

```
alias e="atom -nw"
```

in your `.bashrc` and then run `e file-to-edit.txt` whenever you want to edit a file in Atom.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will stick to opening  atom through the command line explicitly.

Comment: This answer is useless, the question is common and simple, no one wants TextEdit to show up when they click ANY sort of text file, the default should always point to Atom (or whatever editor).

Answer (score 7):

[thee's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163674/172520) doesn't work for Yosemite and El Capitan - use this one instead:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.github.atom;}'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Note, this requires a restart after the command (at least it did for me on High Sierra).

Answer (score 7):

The actual answer is:

`export EDITOR="/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom -nw"`

Answer (score 3):

Just right (or control) click a file of the type you want to change and:

"Get Info" -> "Open with:" -> (Select your program of choice) -> "Change All"

You'll have to do this once for each extension (.txt, .rtf, etc.) you wish to update.

Comment: This was the only one that helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22141204/1692291) answer on Stackoverflow, the following command should work:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.github.atom;}'
```

I am not sure how fare this works through. For me, `open /etc/hosts` opened the file in Atom as expected, but `open demo.properties` did not.

Edit: Might not work on Yosemite and above, see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228711/63717) answer for a modified version.

Comment: demo.properties possibly is not registered as a text file

Comment: This does not work on macOS Mojave or higher.